# Unable to read the timestamp of Zsh history

Tags: timestamp, zsh

**Problem:** to understand the following timestamp

```
1241036430
```

at ~/.history

```
: 1241036336:0;vim ~/.zshrc
: 1241036379:0;vim ~/bin/HideTopBar
: 1241036421:0;ls
: 1241036430:0;cat ~/.history
```

when I have

```
setopt EXTENDED_HISTORY
HISTFILE=~/.history
```

in .zshrc.

**How can you read the timestamp?**

Comment: I am curious about what the second integer (looks to always be 0) is. What does this number represent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simple [util](http://perl.plover.com/classes/mybin/samples/source/localtime), called `localtime` is gold for reading files with timestamps:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# http://perl.plover.com/classes/mybin/samples/source/localtime

if ($ARGV[0] eq '-f') {
  *show_localtime = \&show_localtime_list;
  shift;
}

if (@ARGV) {
  for (@ARGV) {
    print show_localtime($_), "\n";
  }
} else {
  while (<>) {
    s/^(\d+)/show_localtime($1)/e;
    print;
  }
}


sub show_localtime {
  my $t = shift;
  scalar localtime $t;
}

sub show_localtime_list {
  my $t = shift;
  my @a = localtime $t;
  "@a\n"
}
```

- (There is also a little [presentation](http://perl.plover.com/classes/mybin/samples/slide017.html) :))

It handles lots of cases, and seem to understand both timestamps in seconds and mini-seconds, etc.

```
$ localtime < ~/.histfile
<snip>
: Sat Sep 17 05:55:17 2016:0;cat localtime
```

Comment: Can you use the function for other history files, not only Zsh's one?

Comment: Yup, it usually just works. It simply look for the first string of digits and converts that to a human readable date.

Answer (score 22):

Try `history -d`.  Or just type `history -` and press control-D to get all the various options:

```
% history -
-D  -- print elapsed times
-E  -- dd.mm.yyyy format time-stamps
-d  -- print time-stamps
-f  -- mm/dd/yyyy format time-stamps
-i  -- yyyy-mm-dd format time-stamps
-m  -- treat first argument as a pattern
-n  -- suppress line numbers
-r  -- reverse order of the commands
```

Comment: Learnt new thing that ctrl-D will give all options. Thanks you!!

Comment: What do you mean "not working" — `history -d` or tab completion on `history -`? What happens when you try?

Comment: If this doesn't work, check what `history` is aliased to (mine was `fc -l 1`, which won't take any further options). The zsh `history` builtin calls `fc -l`, which you can use with the above options: `fc -l -d`, for example.

Comment: Does not work and gives this: `fc: event not found: -d`

Comment: Make sure you are typing `fc -l` (ell), not `fc -1` (one).

Answer (score 12):

You can display the whole history with human-readable timestamps using this one-liner taken from [an answer on the zsh mailing list](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2007/msg00955.html):

```
perl -lne 'm#: (\d+):\d+;(.+)# && printf "%s :: %s\n",scalar localtime $1,$2' $HISTFILE
```

I would recommend piping the output to a pager (`less` for example) to make it more readable.

Answer (score 3):

**Converting timestamps with awk**

If you want to read the file itself, to use with, say, `grep` or any other filter, you need to convert timestamps.

I made this script, which I save it in my `/usr/local/bin`, and it works for **bash** and **zshell**:

**Script uhistory.awk** at /usr/local/bin/uhistory.awk

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{ 
        if (match($0,/^#/)) # bash
        {
                nlin++
                #adata="@"substr($0,2) 
                #printf("%s ", adata)
                cmdata = "date -d \"@" substr($0,2) "\" +\"%F %H:%M:%S\"" 
                cmdata | getline datado
                close(cmdata)
                printf("%d %s ", nlin, datado)
        }
        else
        if (match($0,/^:/)) # zshell
        {
            nlin++
            split($0, arr, ":|;")
            cmdata = "date -d \"@" substr(arr[2],2) "\" +\"%F %H:%M:%S\"" 
            cmdata | getline datado
            close(cmdata)
            printf("%d : %s ; %ss % ", nlin, datado, arr[3])
            for (i in arr)
            {
                if (i < 4)
                    continue
                printf("%s ", arr[i])
            }
            printf("\n")
        }
        else
        {
            print $0
        }
}
```

**Usage**: you can pipe the history through the filter. Suppose the history file for `zsh`, that has the format:

```
:timestamp:duration;commands
```

Without the **uhistory.awk** filter would be:

```
% head ~/.config/zsh/zhistfile

: 1570482839:0;la
: 1570482839:0;cd zsh
: 1570482839:0;ls
: 1570482839:1;cat verybigaliasfile.txt
: 1570482839:0;alias
: 1570482839:0;ls -la
: 1570482839:0;vi .zshrc
: 1570482839:0;alias
```

With the **uhistory.awk** filter, it would show as:

```
% head ~/.config/zsh/zhistfile | uhistory.awk | grep alias

4 : 2019-10-07 18:13:59 ; 1s % cat verybigaliasfile.txt
5 : 2019-10-07 18:13:59 ; 0s % alias 
9 : 2019-10-07 18:13:59 ; 0s % alias
```

But if your usage doesn't involve treating the file itself, all you really need is just an alias.

Add this line to your `.zsh_aliases` or some other place you have for your aliases.

```
alias history='fc -il 1'
```

or some other option from `fc` command. Check with `man zshbuiltins`

---

Even better is to use the same command, so it is not confusing in case you want to add another key/option at the end. In this case I recommand:

```
alias history='history -i'
```

And of course you can just pipe the result, for example:

```
% history | grep alias

4   2019-10-07 18:13:59  cat verybigaliasfile.txt
5   2019-10-07 18:13:59  alias 
9   2019-10-07 18:13:59  alias
```

In this case, *duration* won't appear, but the rest is the same.

Comment: How does this work when you want to grep the histfile?

Comment: I rewrote the whole answer, and now I explained the simple alias plus grep, and also with a custom filter `uhistory.awk`

Comment: Thank you, your script is really helpful

Comment: I'm glad it served you well.

Answer (score 2):

Adendum: You can use the `history` command itself to translate timestamps found in saved history files as well:

The options to the `history` command as explained by Nicholas Riley apply just as well to saved history files, so `history -d < historyfile` (or any of the other options) translates the timestamps just fine.

This comes in handy if you're using more than just one history file - I've setup `zsh` to keep one history file per pty to avoid mixing up histories from shells running in parallel on the same system (since usually each window/screen/... is particular to a certain task, and so the histories emerging from normal use end up sort of themed).

Comment: `history -d < historyfile` doesn't work for me.. It just prints the current history, not the history given by the file.

Answer (score 2):

```
: 1241036430:0;cat ~/.history

‘: <beginning time>:<elapsed seconds>;<command>’.
```

extendedhistory - saves the time in seconds. The beginning time is since the epoch.

source: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-EXTENDEDHISTORY