# How to interpret the large numbers appearing in each line of zsh history?

Tags: zsh, history

When I look at zsh history, I can see a large number in each line of zsh history

```
: 1264213583:0;cd
```

What is that number?

Comment: What is zhistory? There is no such command in the default zsh install. Is it from some add-on? What is the exact command that creates this output?

Comment: @Jens I am pretty sure he is talking about the zsh history file. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804120/unable-to-read-the-timestamp-of-zsh-history

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither I know nor I ever used zhistory, but that number really seems to be a timestamp value.

It corresponds to [*Sat, 23 Jan 2010 02:26:23 GMT*](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm)

Comment: Also, see `man zshoptions` under the entry `EXTENDED_HISTORY` and `SHARE_HISTORY`.